# Why are the degrees of f(t) and g(z) related in this identity?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions, rational-functions

I am reading "Computing the Continuous Discretely" by Mattias Beck and Sinai Robins and am working on the following exercise (3.13) which is to prove the following:

If $$\sum_{t\geq 0}f(t)z^t = \frac{g(z)}{(1-z)^{d+1}},$$

then $f$ is a polynomial of degree d if and only if $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d$ and $g(1)\neq 0$.

I think that if $deg(g) > d+1$, then the LHS is an improper rational function and could be written as a quotient and remainder, that is something that is not of the form of the RHS. I also know that $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{d+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n + d \choose d}z^n.$$ Since $f(t)$ is not a polynomial in $z$, I am guessing that the condition requiring $deg(f) = d$ might be related to the above identity although I'm not really sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly mentioned, there is an expansion
$$
q(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^{d+1}} = \sum\limits_t \binom{t+d}{d} z^t.
$$
If $g(z) = g_0 + g_1 z + \dots + g_d z^d$, it means that, generally,

$$\begin{align}
f(t) &= [z^t] g(z) q(z) \\
&= [z^t] \sum\limits_{i=0}^d g_i z^i q(z) \\
&= \sum\limits_{i=0}^d g_i [z^{t-i}] q(z) = \boxed{\sum\limits_{i=0}^d g_i \binom{t-i+d}{d}}
\end{align}
$$
The later expression *is* a polynomial in $t$ of degree *at most* $d$. Note that any polynomial $f(t)$ of degree at most $d$, in turn, can be represented as such linear combination, that is, it is always possible to find $g_0, \dots, g_d$ for which the identity holds (see [falling factorial basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)).

The property $g(1) \neq 0$ is same as saying that $g(z)$ is not divisible by $z-1$ due to little Bézout's theorem. In other words, it means that the fraction can not bet reduced and $d$ is the minimum possible for which it can be represented like this. This implies that the bound on $d$ is tight, thus $d$ is exactly the degree of $f(t)$.

**P.S.** There are, of course, other, more insightful, ways to show it. For example, this generating function identity highlights the fact that any polynomial of degree $d$ is a [linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) with characteristic polynomial being simply $(x-1)^{d+1}$. Yet another possible way to prove the result in the question is by taking [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of $f(t)$ for $d$ times and analyzing the result.